# Can't pass data from child to parent

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass data from the child component to the parent component by calling a function. In the parent element I create a function that receives a value as a parameter and calls `setLogin` passing this received value. I call this function in the child component passing the data I want to send as a parameter. When I print the `login` variable in the parent component, it prints an object with the empty email.

I've done this before and it worked, but now it's not working.

What am I forgetting?

Login.js:

```
import "../styles/Login.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function Login({ childToParentLogin }){
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

    async function handleSubmit(){
       if(email.length === 0){
        alert("Enter your e-mail.");
       }else if(password.length === 0){
        alert("Enter your password.");
       }else{
        const url = "http://localhost/metric/src/api/login.php";

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("email", email);
        formData.append("password", password);

        try {
            const data = await Axios.post(url, formData);
            if(data.data === "Correct data"){
                childToParentLogin(email);
                window.location.href="http://localhost:3000/login/usuario";
            }
            setResponse(data.data);
        }catch(erro){
            console.log(erro);
        }
       }
    }
    return (
        ...
    );
}

export default Login;
```

RouteSwitch.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import App from "../App";
import Login from "./Login";
import Register from "./Register";
import User from "./User";
import Test from "./Test";
import { useState } from "react";

function RouteSwitch(){
    const [login, setLogin] = useState({email: ""});

    function childToParentLogin(childData){
        setLogin({email: childData});
        console.log(login);
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Nav></Nav>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" exact element={<App />} />
                <Route path="/login" exact element={<Login childToParentLogin={ childToParentLogin } />} />
                <Route path="/login/user" exact element={<User login={ login } />} />
                <Route path="/register" exact element={<Register />} />
                <Route path="/test" exact element={<Test />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default RouteSwitch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the value of `login` before the state has had a chance to update. If you were to change the value in the console log as shown below, it would print the new email address.

```
function childToParentLogin(childData){
    setLogin({email: childData});
    console.log(childData);
}
```

If you are wanting to do something with the login data *after* if has changed, you should use a `useEffect` hook with `login` as a value in the dependency array.

Comment: When using useEffect to test the console.log, I noticed that it prints the object once with the e-mail filled in and twice with the empty e-mail. You know why?       
 useEffect(() => {
        console.log(login);
    }, [login]);

Comment: Yep. That's because it calls the effect once on mount and then any other time that the value of `login` changes. This includes if it changes to an empty object. If you want to be more specific within the effect, you can wrap the logic inside of an if statement. Something like "if the object is not empty... do something". Check out this page for more info on how to use the hook: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

Comment: But do you know why the variable value is changing to empty?

Comment: My guess is that the `Login` component is remounting for some reason. Any time that the component mounts, it will go back to the default value

Comment: In the console, in the bundle.js file, it prints the value that was informed, then the console prints the RouteSwitch.js file twice more with the empty values.

Comment: The problem is that I am redirecting to another page after login using the JavaScript command `window.locate.href`, it makes React re-render and the variables go back to the default value.

Comment: Using useNavigate it is possible to change the page user without having to render the page again. Thanks!